# Conflict in jar usage under plugins

Tags: corda

I'm trying to deploy Corda nodes in a windows server. While saving the corda app jar in plugins folder, which jar file do I have to save? Should I generate jar using intellij artifacts or just copy the plugins file from respective nodes which was created using gradlew deployNodes command?

Comment: Language, grammar

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood your question correctly, the easiest way would be to grab the jar(s) that are created inside the respective node's plugins folder after you've run deployNodes

Comment: here, am trying to deploy nodes in windows server using https://docs.corda.net/head/deploying-a-node.html . i can able to run the nssm.bat file using powershell. But i couldn't hit webservices after this step.

Comment: how this step ll link my cordapp to nodes?

Comment: The nodes automatically pick up all the CorDapps placed in the plugins folder